# cannot connect CentOS VM NAT Connection to actual NIC

Tags: networking, centos

I have configured a NAT connection on Centos 6.5 VM and it seems it does not connect to my NIC.

service network restart        returns
Bringing up interface eth1: Error: No suitable device found: no device found for connection 'eth1'

ifconfig -a is shown below

> eth2    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0C:29:90:6C:31
>
> UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
>
> RX Packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
> TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
> collisions:0 Base address:0x2024

Answer (score 0):

Well your ifconfig states that you have eth2 device. It is my assumption that you originally had it bridged and changed into NAT.

In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Create file named ifcfg-eth2

And fill it so it would be configured automatically by DHPC server:

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=dhcp 
ONBOOT=yes
```

I am not sure if it should have rights to be executed (chmod +x).